# How to get multiple row items as different column in one sqlite command

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table looks like this:

```
Timestamp  direction  John  Mary  car   airplan

 4960        1        1   null   1     null
 5960        2        1     1   null    1  
 6960        1      null  null   1      1
 7960        1        1   null  null    1
 8960        2        1   null  null   null
```

the record means : john/mary/together go/back to xxx by car/airplan at timestamp
and I wish to have one single sqlite query to get the result like this:

```
          John_t          Mary_t       car_t      airplan_t
          0                0           6960        7960
          8960            5960            0          0
```

which means the **latest** timestmap of (john, mary, car, airplan ) **(go/back)** to xxx.

I try the sql command , but failed...

```
select
(case when John=1 then max(Timestamp) else 0 end) as John_t, 
(case when Mary=1 then max(Timestamp) else 0 end) as Mary_t,
(case when car=1 then max(Timestamp) else 0 end) as car_t,
(case when airplan=1 then max(Time) else 0 end) as airplan_t
 from table where 4960 < Time < 8960 and group by direction
```

can anyone help?

Comment: It's not clear to me how the entries in the table are linked together and what the result should mean. Maybe you should *explain* what the result should *mean*. Despite that, I got the feeling that this table design is very bad because you are trying to store very different information in one table. Maybe you should read up on relational database design and [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: for example, if record is (4960, 1, 1, null, 1, null) means John go to Afriica by car; if record is (5960, 2, 1, 1, null, null) means John and marry back to Africa by airplane.
the result means John back to Africa at 8960, Mary back to Africa at 5960. car is rented to go to Africa at 6960. take airplan when go to Africa at 7960.
I know that the table design is very bad, however, I can't change the table.

Comment: So, is this summary of your question correct: *"For every one of the four (John, Mary, car, airplan), take just the latest recorded timestamp, but put it in the row that corresponds to the direction of the latest movement. So, if John's and Mary's last recorded movement was in the direction = 2, the timestamps are displayed in the second row, and as car's and airplan's last movements were direction = 1, the timestamps are displayed in the other row"*?

Comment: yes, Andriy! sorry my description is not very clear, your statement is what I mean! and " if last recorded movement was in direction=2, then the timestamp in direction=1 needs to fill 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [comment by Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771135/how-to-get-multiple-row-items-as-different-column-in-one-sqlite-command/20787246#comment31138924_20771135), here is the answer:

```
select John_t, Mary_t, car_t, airplan_t from
    -- John --
    (select direction, (case when Timestamp=max_Timestamp then Timestamp else 0 end) as John_t from
        (
        (select dir.direction as direction, max(Timestamp) as Timestamp from
            (select distinct direction from trips) as dir
            left outer join
            (select * from trips where John = 1) as t
            on dir.direction = t.direction
            group by direction
        )
        cross join
        (select max(Timestamp) as max_Timestamp from trips where John = 1)
        )
    )
    natural join
    -- Mary --
    (select direction, (case when Timestamp=max_Timestamp then Timestamp else 0 end) as Mary_t from
        (
        (select dir.direction as direction, max(Timestamp) as Timestamp from
            (select distinct direction from trips) as dir
            left outer join
            (select * from trips where Mary = 1) as t
            on dir.direction = t.direction
            group by direction
        )
        cross join
        (select max(Timestamp) as max_Timestamp from trips where Mary = 1)
        )
    )
    natural join
    -- car --
    (select direction, (case when Timestamp=max_Timestamp then Timestamp else 0 end) as car_t from
        (
        (select dir.direction as direction, max(Timestamp) as Timestamp from
            (select distinct direction from trips) as dir
            left outer join
            (select * from trips where car = 1) as t
            on dir.direction = t.direction
            group by direction
        )
        cross join
        (select max(Timestamp) as max_Timestamp from trips where car = 1)
        )
    )
    natural join
    -- airplan --
    (select direction, (case when Timestamp=max_Timestamp then Timestamp else 0 end) as airplan_t from
        (
        (select dir.direction as direction, max(Timestamp) as Timestamp from
            (select distinct direction from trips) as dir
            left outer join
            (select * from trips where airplan = 1) as t
            on dir.direction = t.direction
            group by direction
        )
        cross join
        (select max(Timestamp) as max_Timestamp from trips where airplan = 1)
        )
    )
;
```

#### A brief explaination (from inner selects to outer):

1. We `left outer join` all possible directions with all "trips" of John/Mary/car/airplan. This ensures that there is a row for each direction for each John, Mary, car and airplan. This is needed to fill in `0` later even if there was no "trip" in that direction.
2. We "reduce" this to the maximum timestamp (`max(Timestamp)`) for each direction (`group by direction`) since we are not interested in earlier trips in the same direction.
3. The result is cross joined with the overall maximum timestamp of John/Mary/car/airplan to allow replacing the lower timestamps with `0` using

   ```
   (case when Timestamp=max_Timestamp then Timestamp else 0)
   ```
4. We do this for each John, Mary, car and airplan and finally `natural join` everything together.

Comment: This is by far the sickest query I've build up to now. xD